# Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined

Tags: jquery, node.js, socket.io

i am new to node.js and try making a simple chat app with nodejs but i can't get this error " Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined ".
I know this is an error talked about a lot in here. But after a few posts found via google it still didn't solve my problem.

nodejs file

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(2000);

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/chat.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
    socket.on('send message',function(data){
        io.sockets.emit('new message',data);
    });
});
```

and html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chat with node and socket io</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #chat{
            height: 400px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chat"></div>
    <form id="send_message">
        <input id="message"/>
        <button type="submit">send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script scr="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        var socket = io.connect();
        var messageForm = $('#send_message');
        var messageBox = $('#message');
        var chat = $('#chat');

        messageBox.submit(function(e){
            e.preventdefault();
            socket.emit('send message',messageBox.val());
            messageBox.val('');
        });

        socket.on('new message',function(data){
            chat.append(data + "<br/>");
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the URL you're calling the page with?

Comment: Voting to close as this turned out to just be a  typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script scr="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

`scr` != `src`

Comment: @utsav It happens to all of us. A lot. FWIW, particularly when using the same variable name on client and server, it's useful to indicate from *where* the error came, e.g., on the server or client side.